# Express server does not receive request, http module server does

Tags: node.js, http, express, tcp, mean-stack

I am making a HTTP server for a Biometric device. I cannot make changes to the devices firmware. I can just add the server ip.

So I first made an express server to receive requests, but it didnt receive any. Later I made a server using http module of Nodejs and voila it was able to do so. 
The problem is writing a server for a very big application in http module would be difficult and there is very less support available for it. I'd prefer to user Express. Any Ideas why express is failing?

Edit:
So someone asked for code here they are:

http module

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 7005;

var s = http.createServer();
s.on('request', function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  console.log(request.method);
  console.log(request.headers);
  console.log(request.data);
  response.write('hi');
  response.end();
});

s.listen(port);
console.log('Browse to http://127.0.0.1:' + port);
```

Express Server:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

// respond with "hello world" when a GET request is made to the homepage
app.all('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('hello world')
   console.log(req.method + " Request Aayi");
   console.log(req.body); 
});

app.listen(7005);
```

Comment: can you provide both the code and more detail about it?

Comment: Added the code snippets. I think Express needs some kind of config.

Comment: I don't see any issues here. I am able to hit `http://localhost:7005/` and get `hello world` from your express code.

Comment: You can try to merge both examples. `var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);` http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen